# Resize a bitmap to the full width of the widget

Tags: android, bitmap, widget

I have created an Android widget that shows a graph. The widget includes an ImageView that stretches to the full size of the widget (match_parent for width and height). I create a bitmap programmatically and draw the graph on it, then set the ImageView's bitmap to the created bitmap.

Everything works fine except the fact that I cannot get the exact dimensions of the available widget space, so the graph takes only a part of the widget (it does not stretch to the available widget area). The problem lies in the fact that when I create the bitmap I have to give it the size - I get the size of the widget from the OPTION_APPWIDGET_MAX_WIDTH and OPTION_APPWIDGET_MAX_HEIGHT widget parameters.

On most devices the widget looks correct, however on some others it does not (I have noticed this on launchers that support 5 icons per row - it looks like the OPTION_APPWIDGET_MAX_WIDTH value is for 4 icons/columns instead of 5).

The best would be if I could get the size of the bitmap from the size of the ImageView on the widget, however this is not possible for RemoteViews, as far as I know (and read).

I have seen another widget that seems to be doing this correctly so there is probably a better way to get the size of the widget at runtime.

Is anyone familiar with this? Can I get the actual width and height of a home screen widget at runtime? Note that I have also tried getting the widget size from the onAppWidgetOptionsChanged function but the result is the same.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exact answer but I can give a guide:

notice that the Screen is a **pixel** size but your widget is based on **dp** or **sp**.

The main thing is to consider all of several types they change into.

Comment: I will accept this answer even if it does not fix the problem completely (the widget size units are indeed in dp and must be converted to pixels when creating the bitmap). The problem that remains now is the different height allocated to widgets by different launchers and settings (rows per screen).